# Selenium timeout exception on save_screenshot on very large windows

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get screenshots of a large map and I am occasionally running into the timeout exception during the execution of the save_screenshot function. It's hard to identify exactly what is causing it, although I observe that the exception occurs when the screenshot I am attempting to take is especially large (eg `10000 x 7200`).

It's not a page load timeout, because I am still able to open the url and interact with elements. The exception is being caught when I take a screenshot (ie `driver.save_screenshot(filename))`).

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 8.743
  (Session info: headless chrome=80.0.3987.163)
```

**What I have tried so far:**

- checking that my **chromedriver**, **chrome browser** and **selenium client (python)** are all up to date ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630332/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-10-000/59635244#59635244)): I am using Chromium 80.0.3987.163, ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106, and Selenium 3.141.0.
- setting the following options (sources [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450594/selenium-timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514022/chrome-webdriver-produces-timeout-in-selenium), [3](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=942023)):

```
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--enable-automation')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-browser-side-navigation')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor')
options.add_argument('--dns-prefetch-disable')
options.add_argument('--headless')
```

Any pointers to resolving this issue are very welcome!

Comment: How does you get this larger size 10000 x 7200 of screen ?

Comment: @SariqShaikh You can configure window sizes with `driver.set_window_size(width, height)`

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114639/timed-out-receiving-message-from-renderer-0-100-log-messages-using-chromedriver/60140212#60140212

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer specifically to this problem (I had the same issue!)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56364166/15567914

basically add this to the options:

```
options.add_argument("--force-device-scale-factor=1")
```