# Selenium Timed out receiving message from renderer on python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

After Chrome released their newest stable version (89.0.4389.90), I am now receiving this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 291.642
> (Session info: headless chrome=89.0.4389.90)

My Python code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # maybe needed if running on Windows.
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver', options=options)
urls = "https://www.google.com/"
driver.get(urls) #here I have the error
```

(my chromedriver is 89.0.4389.23 is the unic)

Can anybody help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would refer to this previous post, where you might find several useful workarounds : [Chrome Webdriver produces timeout in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40514022/11246056)

Comment: that solution doesn't work for me and I use Centos 8 not Macbook